# How to call async/await Winforms

Tags: c#, sql-server

I wonder if I can make my system responsive or it shows the user that its loading some data for a short time and show my `WaitForm` while the program loads another `Form`. Because my system pause for a short time whenever a show another `Form`.

For example: I have here my `FrmLogin` and when the user inputs his `Username` and `Password`, I want it to shows my `WaitForm` while loading the other forms, but when I use `async/await` the programs stops,

Here is the code:

```
private async void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SystemDatabase"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(conn);
        sqlconn.Open();
        string query = "Select * from UserAccount where Username = @Username and Password = @Password";
        SqlCommand mycommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlconn);
        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text);
        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);
        SqlDataReader sdr = mycommand.ExecuteReader();
        if (sdr.Read() == true)
        {
            if (sdr["Designation"].ToString() == "Cashier")
            {
                FrmWait waitfrm = new FrmWait();
                waitfrm.Show();
                FrmPOS frm = new FrmPOS();
                frm.Show();
                frm.lblCashierName.Text = sdr["FullName"].ToString();
                waitfrm.Close();
            }
            else if (sdr["Designation"].ToString() == "Admin")
            {
                FrmWait waitfrm = new FrmWait();
                waitfrm.Show();
                Form1 frm = new Form1();
                frm.Show();
                frm.lblFullname.Text = sdr["FullName"].ToString();
                frm.lblPosition.Text = sdr["Designation"].ToString();
                byte[] imgBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(sdr["IDPicture"].ToString());
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgBytes))
                {
                    frm.pbuser.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
                }
                FrmStockIn fsi = new FrmStockIn();
                fsi.txtStockinby.Text = sdr["FullName"].ToString();
                waitfrm.Close();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("User not Exist!", "My POS", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
    });
}
```

Any solution or suggestion would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Look at `BeginInvoke`.

Comment: I usually use a backgroundworker with a Winform so the form doesn't lock when data is being updated.  I usually have to use an Invoke when the backgroundworker is filling a form to prevent cross-threading issues.

Comment: Are you really storing plaintext passwords in the database? Also, [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: `Task.Run` will run the code on a thread pool thread which is not what you want if you do something UI.related there. Remove it and instead `await mycommand.ExecuteReaderAsync()`

Comment: Does it really take so long to look up a user that you have to put up a "please wait" loading spinner? I'd say you have other issues

Comment: @KlausGütter Thanks.

Comment: @CaiusJard its not that long but i dont want my system to freeze even if its 1 sec.

Comment: *Even if it's 1 sec* - the user won't notice 1 second

Comment: @CaiusJjust want my system to be responsive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like Klaus said, remove your `await Task.Run` and await running the reader instead..

But also it looks like you're wrapping a waiting form around your `new Form1`/`new FrmPOS` calls - if those constructors do any heavy IO that is taking long or jamming up you would be better off moving that code to a form load event (so at least it can be made async) or a separate method that is async, so that it can be awaited and doesn't jam the UI thread/make your wait form go "not responding"

I would also look at making those forms responsible for showing the wait form if they know it's gonna take long, not this form

Your life would become much simpler if you use Dapper, by the way:

```
//create a class to represent the user; Dapper will query the database and populate this class with information automatically
public class PosUser{
    public string FullName{get;set;}
    public string Designation{get;set;}
    public string IDPicture{get;set;}
}

private async void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    
    string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SystemDatabase"].ConnectionString;

    PosUser r;

    using(sqlconn = new SqlConnection(conn)){

        var query = "Select designation, fullname from UserAccount where Username = @Username and Password = @Password";

        var r = await conn.QuerySingleOrDefaultAsync<PosUser>(
            query,
            new {
                Username = txtUsername.Text,
                Password = txtPassword.Text.GetHashcode() //at least make some effort to obscure passwords in the db!
            }
        );
    }

    if(r == default){
        MessageBox.Show("User not Exist!", "My POS", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        return;
    }

    FrmWait waitfrm = new FrmWait();
    waitfrm.Show();

    if(r.Designation == "Cashier")
    {
        FrmPOS frm = new FrmPOS(); //if this does heavy io, move the io to a method you can call async
        await frm.DoIoInHereAsync(); //like this, or in an async form load
        frm.lblCashierName.Text = r.FullName;
        frm.Show();
    }
    else if (r.Designation == "Admin")
    {
        Form1 frm = new Form1(); //do not do io in here
        await frm.DoIoInHereAsync();
        frm.lblFullname.Text = r.FullName;
        frm.lblPosition.Text = r.Designation;
        byte[] imgBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(r.IDPicture);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgBytes))
        {
            frm.pbuser.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        }
        FrmStockIn fsi = new FrmStockIn(); //do not do io in here
        await fsi.DoIoInHereAsync();
        fsi.txtStockinby.Text = r.FullName;
    }

    
    waitfrm.Close();

}
```